# Using a livecd on an intel iMac

Tags: installation, live-cd, mac

I have a livecd that works on Windows.  When I boot the Mac with it in and hold the option button, it shows the hard drive, a cd called "Windows" and a cd called "EFI boot".  if I click on the Windows cd it says

1. [no text here]
2. [no text here either]

Select cd boot type:

and it doesn't allow me to input anything.  If i click on EFI boot, it gives me a command prompt but I don't know what do do there.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not sure if this is exactly your problem**, but the Ubuntu 12.10 QQ has ISO versions to mac computers. You can see them here:

- [64-bit Mac (AMD64) desktop image - Ubuntu 12.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/)

Try it! ;)

Comment: I'll give it a try, but this is a 32 bit mac, so I'm not sure if it will work